# Game characters stop moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating my first Unity game and I have an **enemy** character, that travels from left corner to the right perfectly fine, but then I have a **prefab (copy of that character)** that suddenly stops moving, but when I pick him up with the ***Location tool*** the character starts moving again and then stops again. I am using **Unity 5.2.3f1 version**.

Here is the code that I'm using

```
public class EnemyPatrol : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    public bool moveRight;

    public float wallCheckRadius;
    public Transform wallCheck;
    public LayerMask whatIsWall;
    private bool hittingWall;

    private bool notAtEdge;
    public Transform edgeCheck;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity=new Vector2(3,0);
        //Debug.Log("Premikam se desno   "+GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity);

        //hittingWall = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (wallCheck.position, wallCheckRadius, whatIsWall);
        wallCheckRadius = 0.6f;
        notAtEdge = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (edgeCheck.position, wallCheckRadius, whatIsWall);


        hittingWall = false;
        //notAtEdge = true;
        if (hittingWall || !notAtEdge) {
            moveRight = !moveRight;
            Debug.Log ("Zadene steno " + hittingWall + "  Ni na robu  " + notAtEdge);
        }
        // Prepreci krozenje igralca ( zabavna zadeva )
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;

        if (moveRight) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity=new Vector2(3,0);
            Debug.Log("Premikam se desno   "+GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity);
        } else {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity=new Vector2(-3,0);
            Debug.Log("Premikam se levo"+GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a picture of how it looks in game.

[image]

-**Circle Collider** shows the collider range of the "kill zone", if the player touches it he dies.

-**Box Collider** checks if he is on the ground

-**Green ball** checks if he gets to the corner

-**Yellow ball** checks if he hits a wall (which I don't really use here but have it just in case if I need it)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do physics in Update.

...well, you can, but this breaks Unity. All sorts of weird stuff will happen. Everywhere in the docs they're explicit about "don't do that".

For anything involving Physics, you use FixedUpdate instead.

---

Also, you should be attaching scripts to the detector things themselves. You should be implementing them as triggers, and using OnTriggerEntered etc.

Let Unity physics do the work for you - that's what it's there for.

e.g. read about: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html